# Is it misfortune or small misfortune

Tags: adjectives

Some people complain when they encounter a **small misfortune** in the course of their thoroughly happy life.

Using **small** with misfortune, does it make sense. Can misfortune be small or big?

Comment: Yes. A small misfortune - there is a banana peel on the road, a person slipped and hurt his elbow. A big misfortune - there is a banana peel on the road, a person slipped, hit his head on a sharp rock then died.

Comment: Take note that it is relative. To some, slipping and hurting an elbow may already be considered a big misfortune.

Comment: I would call someone's death due to a simple peel on the road a *tragedy* rather than a "big misfortune." You can use the word "tragedy" to refer to things that truly should not have happened, especially if it involves death.

Comment: @CrazyEyes - I agree with you, but shin's larger point stands. A bruised elbow might be a small misfortune, a broken arm a big misfortune, and an accidental death a tragedy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can, but we don't see those adjectives put in front of that word very often.

Check out the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small%20misfortune%2Cbig%20misfortune&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) with *small misfortune* and *big misfortune*:

[image]
and then [look at what happens](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small%20misfortune%2Cbig%20misfortune%2C%20a%20misfortune&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) when you add *a misfortune*:
[image]

So, the short answer is that you *can*, but most of the time, this word is descriptive enough on its own.

Comment: To J.R. and the OP, this may be worth noting. Being curious, I added `little misfortune` to the first chart, and found that it edges over `small misfortune`. But the real winner is `great misfortune`, which is not far behind `a misfortune`. :-)